# JQuery click event not working for html input (check box) inside asp:Gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

Inside an aspx file I have Grid view under asp:panels under an Update Panel

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="PnlTraveler" runat="server" Visible="false">
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ...>
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <table border="0" style="width: 100%">
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlVisualAst" runat="server" Visible="false">
   <tr>
     <td style="text-indent: 50px; width: 25%">
      <asp:Label ID="lblVisAst" runat="server" Text="Visual Assitance"></asp:Label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input id="chkBoxVisAst" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" enableviewstate="true" />
     </td>
     <img alt="" src="Images/Ram_Rebel_Reveal-354-331x220.jpg"/ class="overlay_div" style="display:none">
     </tr>
   </asp:Panel> 
 </table>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TemplateField
 </Columns> 
</asp:Gridview>
</asp:Panel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

It works if I code my JQuery like the following way

**JQUERY**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('ready', function ()
    {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function ()
        {
            $('.checkbox').change('click', function ()
            {
                    $('.overlay_div').dialog
                   ({
                       title: "my jquery popup",
                       width: 430,
                       height: 200,
                       modal: true,
                       button:
                           {
                               Close:
                               function () {
                                   $(this).dialog('Close');
                               }
                           }
                   });
            });
        });

    });
```

If I declare my Check boxes under the Gridview(GridView1) with a CSS class = 'checkbox', then on that change event of the particular class the Jquery generates all the events associated with that checkbox class. If I wanna show only one Pop Up window with the change event it shows 4 checkboxes because the Gridview1 is supposed to show 4 checkboxes with same CSS class='checkbox'

How can I detect the event generated from each dynamic checkbox inside that gridview without using CSS class but only with check box id (chkBoxVisAst)?

Comment: `id` should be **unique** per page. Hope you are following that rule. To get the element which triggered the `event`, you might need to use `$(this)` inside on `change event`.

Comment: Would You please give an example brother . @Guruprasad

Comment: Sure, I would give an example but before that you need to clarify few things. You are generating `elements` with duplicate `id` - `chkBoxVisAst`. Aren't you? Why you do not want to use the `class`?

Comment: If I don't use CSS class, I cant get acces to the click event of the checkboxes inside the Grid. But If I use class all the checkboxes are generalized by this class, so I can control change event. But the consequence is that for one click in the checkbox event it generates four operation cause in that gridview dynamically 4 checkboxes are created .

Comment: What 4 operations you are talking about for one `click`?

Comment: Inside the Gridview there are 4 checkboxes which are generated dynamically. It is described in the code above.
If I click one checkbox it should only show one pop up window but it shows 4 windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113956/discussion-between-jabed-hossain-and-guruprasad-rao).

Comment: Your jQuery code appears wrong in many ways i.e.`$('.checkbox').change('click', function ()` kind of says the "change" event on the "click" element - no such `<click></click>` element that I can see but that syntax is just wrong anyway unless you really meant "click" to be data which it is `.change( [eventData ], handler )` https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: `$(document).on('ready', function ()` should only be `$(document).ready(function ()` as "$(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use this peace of code

```
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').find('input:checkbox[id$="chkBoxVisAst"]').click(function ()
```

this portion of code I can actually get any controls `id` from inside the `Gridview`